# Unable to load the data to elasticsearch using kafka-structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I am able to consume the messages from kafka using structured streaming and able to print on the console mode but unable to write it to elastic search. Tried all the available options nothing is working. Unfortunately, I am not getting any error also. Any suggestions ? Am I missing anything?

```
    val kafkaDF = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.KafkaServer) //"x-sin-edp-d-kfk-8-s01.dfs:6667,x-sin-edp-d-kfk-8-s02.dfs:6667"
      .option("subscribe", config.topic) //"uat.push.mulesoft")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      //.option("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
      .load()
```

---

```
    val invoiceWriterQuery = outputDF.writeStream
      //.queryName("Flattened Invoice Writer")
      .outputMode("append")
   //   .format("console")
     .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      //.format("es")
       .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
       .option("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
       .option("es.nodes.client.only", "false")
      .option("es.net.ssl","true")
       .option("es.mapping.id", outputDF.col("key").toString())
       .option("es.write.operation", "upsert")
       .option("es.nodes", config.esnodes )//"https://vpc-dfs-datahub-elastic-dev-j4qxkivimyqieuuzed2ntomviu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/"
       .option("es.port", config.esport)
      .option("es.resource", "loyalty_vw_eod_sls_dtl_test1/doc")
       // .option("path", "output")
       .option("checkpointLocation", "chk-point-dir")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 minute"))
      .start()

    //sf_df.unpersist()
    invoiceWriterQuery.awaitTermination();
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>LoyaltyESWrite</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Loyalty_Write_To_ElasticSearch</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spark.core.version>2.3.1</spark.core.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.7.3</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.core.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <!--<version>${spark.core.version}</version> -->
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.ceedubs</groupId>
        <artifactId>ficus_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>lift-json_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/spark-snowflake -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-snowflake_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5-spark_2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/scala</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                <args>
                    <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                    <arg>-explaintypes</arg>
                    <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                    <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <stdout>W</stdout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all,-serial,-path</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.example.WriteToES</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You've not shown what is `outputDF`

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is the final output like I joined streaming data frame with the other data frame received from snowflakes. I am able to print the results to console so there is problem with the transformations I am applying in between.

Comment: Okay, well, then you need to show that code "in between"

Comment: val valueDF = kafkaDF.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))

        val explodeDFK = valueDF.selectExpr("value.CRM.Member.MembershipCardNo", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.TransactDate", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.ReceiptNo",
          "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.StoreLocation", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.Type", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.TransactionUpdateType", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.DivisionCode", "value.CRM.LoyaltyTransaction.RequestedDate"
        )

Comment: val explodeDF = explodeDFK
          .withColumn("TransactDate", date_format(explodeDFK("TransactDate"), "yyyyMMdd"))

Comment: val query = "select RECEIPTNUMBER,CAST(DIVISION AS VARCHAR) AS DIVISION,CAST(TRANSACTIONDATE AS VARCHAR) AS TRANSACTIONDATE,CAST(LINENUMBER AS VARCHAR) AS LINENUMBER,MEMBERSHIPNUMBER from INSIGHT_DEV.INS_SBI.VW_EOD_SLS_DTL"

Comment: val sf_df: DataFrame = spark.read
          .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
          .options(sfOptions)
          .option("query", query)
          .load()
        sf_df.persist()

Comment: val joinExpr = sf_df.col("RECEIPTNUMBER") === explodeDF.col("ReceiptNo") && sf_df.col("DIVISION") === explodeDF.col("DivisionCode") && sf_df.col("TRANSACTIONDATE") === explodeDF.col("TransactDate")
        val joinType = "inner"

        val joinedDF = sf_df.join(explodeDF, joinExpr, joinType)

Comment: val outputDF = joinedDF.select(col("ReceiptNo") as("RECEIPTNUMBER"), col("DivisionCode") as ("DIVISION"),
          col("TransactDate") as("TRANSACTIONDATE") , col("LINENUMBER"), when(col("MEMBERSHIPNUMBER") === "", "").otherwise( col("MembershipCardNo")) as("MEMBERSHIPNUMBER") )
          .withColumn("key", concat(col("TRANSACTIONDATE"), lit(""), col("DIVISION"), lit(""), col("RECEIPTNUMBER"), lit(""), col("LINENUMBER")))

Comment: Added in a multiple comment as We cant add in a single comment.

Comment: Remove all comments and [edit] your post instead. Also create a [mcve] instead

Comment: All I can tell is that you are doing at least 3 joins here, so potentially `outputDf` never has any data to actually write... You can simply add `outputDf.show(10)` before writing to ES to prove it has data